# Location Manager gives poor accuracy on only (some) Huawei P20

Tags: xamarin.android, gps, locationmanager, huawei-mobile-services

I have an Android app that uses Android.Locations.LocationManager with ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission etc. to get high accuracy locations. It works for most devices but for some reason it doesn't for a lot of P20 users?! Note! Not *all* Huawei P20, but in a much larger degree than let's say Pixel och Samsung users where we have no issues at all. We alo get the problem on a few p30's as well.

I've considered using fused location instead but as it's critical that I get a high degree of accuracy and thus want to use GPS and not WiFi, fused location doesn't seem to really be the solution.

With all the issues I actually purchased a P20 as a test device but with the, at the time, current android version (8.0) we could not replicate the problem. Now with Android 9 we can! The location service is off by an accuracy of +20m. This is with the device option "Improve location accuracy" turned **on**. If I switch it off, we get 4 meters!? However, switching if to off doesn't seem to help all our users...

Anybody know about any specific tricks/implementations that needs to be accounted for for Huawei (P20) devices?

Answer (score 0):

is your question that the device location obtained using Android.Locations.LocatoinManager on Samsung and Huawei phones is inaccurate? 
If yes, you are advised to integrate HMS Core Location Kit into your app for locating. The HMS Core Location Kit can quickly locate the precise device location in seconds thanks to a large amount of crowdsourcing data. For details, visit https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/location-introduction.

Answer (score 0):

In Huawei Phones you have to use HMS Location Kit and in the Manifest file you have to add the given permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

In Android Q, if your app needs to continuously locate the device location when it runs in the background, you need to apply for the **ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION** permission in the Manifest file.

After adding the preceding information to the Manifest file, you need to dynamically apply for the permissions in the code.

To know more about HMS Location yon can visit the link.
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/location-guidev4

https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201227666661190030&fid=0101187876626530001